# Вопросы по алгоритму сжатия Хаффмана

Tags: алгоритм, сжатие

Во первых: Можно ли после сжатия превратитить получившуюся последовательностей 0 и 1 в ТОТ ЖЕ текст?

Во вторых: Возможно ли сжимать что-то кроме текста, если да то как это сделать?

Comment: Что мешает в том-же порядке переводить, а потом разбивать и по числу находить символ из таблицы?

Comment: @And Я спрашиваю не про декомпрессию, мне интересно, можно ли в ЭТОМ состоянии перевести в тот же текст. Надеюсь это возможно

Comment: Вы сами понимаете, о чем говорите? Как вы без декомпрессии вернете в исходное состояние? Прочитайте подробнее про алгоритм сжатия Хаффмана.

Comment: @And Я и спарашивал возможно ли это.

Comment: Возможно, что? Без декомпрессии и перебора по символьно? Нет! Это же логично, также и  сжатие не возможно без алгоритма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Превращение этой последовательности в исходный текст и есть декомпрессия. Идём по последовательности, используя полученное дерево-словарь, и восстанавливаем символы.

Да, сжимать можно любые данные, они ничем не отличаются от "текста", только есть физическое ограничение на объём набора (массива, списка, словаря) счётчиков - для текста это максимум 256 или 65536 счётчиков, а для четырёхбайтных единиц он уже может быть слишком велик.

Comment: А что в изображении или в видео брать вместо символов(как в тексте)?

Comment: байты или слова. Если формат RGB и цветов не слишком много, то и трёхбайтовые структуры RGB

Comment: То-есть нужно превратить файл в 2 вид, после все разбить на байты, и искать одинаковые байты, а потом строить дерево, я правильно понял?

Comment: "2 вид"  или другой - это только представление данных для человека, в компьютере всё бинарное. Любой файл (в т.ч. текстовый) - уже последовательность байтов.

Comment: Ну то-есть получится? Я знаю что в компьютере все бинарное

Comment: Да, получится..

Comment: P.S. Сжатие будет эффективно, если распределение данных неравномерное. Т.е. jpeg, например, сжать уже не получится.